# Basic Poisson expectation question

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm trying to grasp poisson processes once again after taking a statistics course a long time ago.

I want to find $E(X|X>2)$ where $X \sim poi(3)$

My solution so far:

$E(X)=\lambda = rt$ where $r=$ the average rate at which the events occur and $t=$ time interval.

This would have solve the problem if we were given a specific time interval, but the exercise gives just gives me $X>2$ with no upper limit, so therefore I don't know where to go from this.

Would anyone like to give me hint?

Comment: The question  involves  a single r.v. It does not involve a whole process.  You just have to know what Poisson distribution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X|X>2)= \frac {\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} ne^{-3} \frac {3^{n}} {n!}} {\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} e^{-3} \frac {3^{n}} {n!}}$.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining the solution? I don't quite understand why the solution looks the way it does

Comment: By definition: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X>2) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>2})}{\mathsf P(X>2)}\\[1ex] &= \left.\left(\sum_{n>2} n 3^n \mathrm e^{-3} / n! \right)\middle/\left(\sum_{n>2} 3^n \mathrm e^{-3} / n!\right)\right.\end{align}$$However, it may be more useful to note that: $$\begin{align}1&=\mathsf P(X\leq 2)+\mathsf P(X > 2)\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X\leq 2})+\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>2})\end{align}$$